# buttons inside different tabs

Tags: android, button, tabs, android-tabhost, onclicklistener

I have three tabs and each one extends Activity and implements View.OnClickListener
When I selected some tab and click on a button, the OnClickListener implemented into SomeTabActivity doesn't work. Why?
What I need to do to create my activity?
Every time that I select some tab I need start new activity?

My code:

**//the main activity**

```
 public class TripoidActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
         final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
         tabHost.setup();
         final Resources res = getResources();

         createTabA(tabHost, res);
         createTabB(tabHost, res);
         createTabC(tabHost, res);

    }

}
```

**//the tab A activity**

```
 public class TabAActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        buttonAddItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAddItem);
        buttonAddItem.setOnClickListener(TabAActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do something (show a toast msg)
    }

    }
```

**//the main layout xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <include layout="@layout/tab_a" />
            <include layout="@layout/tab_b" />
            <include layout="@layout/tab_c" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

Comment: Why buttonAddItem.setOnClickListener(TabAActivity.this); - why not just 'this' ?

Comment: Is the same thing. But this way "TabAActivity.this" is easiest to see what you refer.

Comment: Made my brain tick over along the lines of "I wonder if this somehow does something with the class rather than the instance of the class I'm currently in". Also potentially risks breaking polymorphism if you modify things. Still, I don;t think this is the problem :-(

Answer (score 1):

Try This...

Main Activity

```
public class TabWidgetExampleActivity extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DailyActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Daily").setIndicator("",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_daily))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MapActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Map").setIndicator("",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_map))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HourlyActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Hourly").setIndicator("",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_hour))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


   }
  }
```

Tab Activity

```
    public class HourlyActivity extends Activity{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final Button btn=new Button(this);
    btn.setText("button");
     final LinearLayout l1=new LinearLayout(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hai", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent i=new Intent();
            i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });
    setContentView(btn);
}

 }
```

Comment: Hi, tks for help.I solved my problem. I just needed to change the "setContent(R.id.tabId)" to "setContent(someIntent)". It's starts a new activity everytime you change the tab.